# wash_out: Accessing Soap Header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wash-out

I need to emulate a soap service that receives authentication credentials through the soap header. Is there a way to access/parse the soap header using the wash_out gem?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns:credentials xmlns:ns="http://somedomain.com/ws">
        <ns:userID ns:encodingType="xsd:string">User</ns:userID>
        <ns:password ns:encodingType="xsd:string">Password</ns:password>
    </ns:credentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wash_out supports only WSSE (Web service security) authentication.

It looks something like that:

```
<soap:Header>        
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="sample" 
       xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
    <wsse:Username>sample</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:44:51Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
```

I believe, if you are using wash_out, you can get headers with something like this (I didn't try this code, I am just looking at https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out/blob/master/lib/wash_out/dispatcher.rb

```
envelope = request.env['wash_out.soap_data'].values_at(:envelope, :Envelope).compact.first
header   = envelope.values_at(:header, :Header).compact.first
userId = header.values_at(:userID, :UserID).compact.first
password = header.values_at(:password, :Password).compact.first
```